# The Marquee effect not work correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I want to realize the marquee effect, some times goes well, sometimes goes wrong, don't know why.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bellahuang/hpqxtdeq/1/)

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menudepth1").children("a").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected")
    })
    function move(){
        var Parent=$("#left-con").find("ul");
        var Img=$("#left-con").find("li").eq(0);
        var Width=Img.width();
        Img.animate({marginLeft:(-1*Width)+"px"},2000,function(){
            $(this).appendTo(Parent).css("marginLeft","0px");

        })
    }
    setInterval(move,2000)  
})
```

Comment: its working in your jsfiddle

Comment: Your interval callback is called before the animation finish. Here is a simple fix which is better than using any interval: https://jsfiddle.net/hpqxtdeq/2/  And here if you want some delay betwwen each image slide: https://jsfiddle.net/hpqxtdeq/3/

Answer (score 1):

A tad bit unrelated to the question, but if you want the code to perform better I would recommend to use CSS transforms instead of margin. The reason being that changing the margin forces the whole page to re-render with every new value while transforms only redraws the element in question.

Especially mobile browsers will love you!

[Here](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/) is a more in depth (albeit a bit long) article about this if you are interested! :)